# Laptop connects to other network but not to my home wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, connection

My home network's wireless SSID is say "XYZ"

I also have an ethernet wire from the same router.

I have two laptops A and B

Earlier both A and B were able to connect to my home internet through the ethernet and wireless.

Suddenly, the laptop B can no longer connect to XYZ or through ethernet. When I do plug the wire, i get the connection icon all green but when I try to access any web page it errors out (page not found)

But strangely laptop B connects to my neighbours wireless SSID "ABC". I have also tested laptop B with other networks and it connects fine.

Laptop A and many other devices still connect fine with my home wireless "XYZ"

Strange thing is when my laptop B connects wireless through XYz, it gets the IP address but then none of the browsers (chrome,firefox, IE) can show any web pages.

What settings should I be checking on laptop B that is preventing it to connect to my home internet.

Thank you

Comment: I presume you're using Windoze?  Have you tried using the "repair" option for the connection?  (This sounds like an IP address issue -- simply getting a new IP address may be all that's needed.)

Answer (score 0):

A) check that your computer has a proper IP for your network (if your working laptop gets something on 192.168.x.x then so should the other)

B) check that you don't have a proxy configured for your web browser.

C) check that you can ping your router from the non-browsing laptop.

I'd focus on first getting the wired connection working first to simplify your troubleshooting. Don't worry about the wireless until you get wired working.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the lack of browsing is a problem with your network. I would do a full malware scan, and make sure that your machine is clean.

A handy tip: if you can ping a domain like google.com, your network connection is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occur due to IP conflict. Below are my recommendation for your problem

1. Try to disable then enable your network adapter both ethernet and wifi.
2. If your ip address setting is manual,try to set up to automatic so that computer b will automatically obtain the available ip.

Answer (score 0):

You should start checking in the following order for your LAPTOP "B"

1. Try to disable and enable your wired and wireless adapter.
2. Troubleshoot problems in Windows is a good option to try as well.
3. Check your router settings to see if IP address allocation is via DHCP. Then check if a proper IP address is allocated to your LAPTOP "B".
4. Disbale all the proxy settings in whatever browser you are using. If not sure, install and try a different browser.
5. Try pinging google.com or even the IP address of your router. Typically your router will have an IP like 192.168.2.1 (but it may differ).
6. Please check if there are any entries in **MAC address filtering** in your router configuration. Remove all the entries from there and disable MAC address filtering and also filtering by IP address (if present).