# Wireless network available to every device except one

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, router, wireless-router

This is basically the same as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/799634/dell-xps-laptop-windows-8-can-connect-to-wireless-perfectly-except-one-network-t) and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/193438/laptop-connects-to-other-network-but-not-to-my-home-wireless?rq=1), but neither of those solutions are working (I'm using WPA2 security, and I can't ping google.com [it returns "request timed out"]).

I have a TP Link router that every single device can connect to except for one laptop. That laptop (running Windows 8) can connect to any other network except for that router. It does not appear in the options when I click on the wireless icon in the taskbar, or in Network Settings. When I connect the router to the laptop with an ethernet cable, nothing happens. It's as though the router might as well not even be there.

I've tried resetting the router, restarting the laptop, starting it in safe mode with networking, and running a virus scan. I'm not sure what else to try. I will be running Device Doctor soon to see if my wireless driver is out of date, because I can't check for updates since I'm offline. I don't think this will be the case, though, since I can connect to other networks except this one.

I don't know if this is relevant, but there's an unknown device connected to my router (wireless and wired) at this time. I don't think it's the laptop in question (since it doesn't match the name of the laptop). See below:

[image]

I'd appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Does your router give IP addresses using DHCP? Maybe all assignable addresses are in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the wireless network adapter driver from the device manager then connect again.
Check the router configuration for any "MAC addressing filter" policy.

Check the (Event Viewer\Applications and Services\Microsoft\Windows\Wireless-Autoconfig) for any error or warnings.